# SAPui5 sap.viz.ui5.StackedColumn yAxis color and spacing

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to change color and spacing for the y axis horizontal lines on a sap viz.

Spacing does not seem to be possible according to docs (deprecated fixedTicks?) and changing color does not work. Always generates yellow lines.

Example:

```
var column = new sap.viz.ui5.StackedColumn({
      dataset : dataset,
      background : new sap.viz.ui5.types.Background({visible : true, drawingEffect : sap.viz.ui5.types.Background_drawingEffect.glossy}),
      legendGroup : new sap.viz.ui5.types.Legend({visible: false}), 
      legend : new sap.viz.ui5.types.legend.Common({visible: false}),
      xAxis : new  sap.viz.ui5.types.Axis({color: "#FFFFFF", lineSize: 3, visible: false}),
      yAxis : new  sap.viz.ui5.types.Axis(
              { visible: true, 
                color: "#FFFFFF",
                axisline: new sap.viz.ui5.types.Axis_axisline({visible: false}),
                gridline: new sap.viz.ui5.types.Axis_gridline({color: "#FFFFFF", size: 1, colour: '#FF0000'}),
                scale: new sap.viz.ui5.types.Axis_scale({fixedRange:true, minValue: -12, maxValue: 12})
              }),
      plotArea : new sap.viz.ui5.types.StackedVerticalBar({colorPalette: ['#ea1d25', '#90b9e1']})
    });
```

The problem is that none of the color Attributes in the yAxis change anything. According to the docs, there is a color attribute. Changing it has no effect. Did this change recently or maybe a known bug?
Regarding the spacing, Documentation says that fixedTicks is deprecated, how to change the spacing so that an horizontal line is drawn with a certain interval?

Docs: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.types.Axis_scale.html

Comment: this guy is setting colors, does this help? http://scn.sap.com/thread/3518432 I tried it myself, but does also not seem to work when setting Min and Max... currently still figuring out the problem, did you progress in the meantime?

Comment: hi, sorry, no. I gave up on trying to set the colors :/ .